# SQL LEFT JOIN, Average and WHERE

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce, left-join, average

So I have been trying this for over a week and a bit, I put it to rest because I couldn't get it to work but this is what I am trying to do;

Select a product from the database > Use LEFT OUTER JOIN to load its rating and make an average of it > Use INNER JOINs for different information (not really important, but I will say it anyway).

This is a simplified (but accurate) replica of my query - the original is quite long and has different language words in it so it might get a bit confusing;

```
SELECT 
PRODUCT.name AS Name,
PRODUCT.price AS Price,
BRAND.name AS Brand,
AVG(RATING.rating) AS Rating
FROM PRODUCT
LEFT OUTER JOIN RATING ON RATING.product_id = PRODUCT.product_id
INNER JOIN BRAND ON BRAND.brand_id = PRODUCT.brand_id
GROUP BY PRODUCT.name, PRODUCT.price, BRAND.name
```

The above works, but it misses the 'filtering' on rating.
I wish adding `WHERE AVG(RATING.rating) > 3` would work, but sadly it doesn't.
Is this in any way possible to do?

Thanks.

Comment: What happens when you add the "where" clause? Does it cause an error? Could you please give us some more details about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `HAVING AVG(RATING.rating) > 3` after your `GROUP BY`.

See [HAVING on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx) for more details.

Comment: :) There are some very fast fingers on SO these days! Sometimes you get lucky.

Comment: Thank you muchly. So simple.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the **[`HAVING` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173260.aspx)**. The **[`WHERE` clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173294%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)** filters the result set *prior to* grouping, whereas the HAVING clause filters the final result set, *after* grouping and aggregation. So in `WHERE` clause you can't use the aggregates (`AVG(RATING.rating)` in this case), whereas in the `HAVING`, you can do so.

```
SELECT 
PRODUCT.name AS Name,
PRODUCT.price AS Price,
BRAND.name AS Brand,
AVG(RATING.rating) AS Rating
FROM PRODUCT
LEFT OUTER JOIN RATING ON RATING.product_id = PRODUCT.product_id
INNER JOIN BRAND ON BRAND.brand_id = PRODUCT.brand_id
GROUP BY PRODUCT.name, PRODUCT.price, BRAND.name
HAVING AVG(RATING.rating) > 3
```